# Using Publishing Service on Azure PaaS

Tags: paas, publishing-service

Has anyone here used Publishing Service on Azure as PaaS?

The client has two databases(two web databases), First, it publishes on the main base then on the "backup" base. I'm thinking of using the Azure SQL replication service but Sitecore has this Publishing service.
What do you think?

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Publishing_Service/31/Sitecore_Publishing_Service_31_Update1.aspx

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Publishing Service is not yet available on Azure PaaS.

It was announced at the symposium to become available for Azure PaaS with Sitecore 9.1 release.

Comment: Thanks, my client use Sitecore 9.0.1. The databases are geographically separated. It takes a long time to publish in this second database.

Comment: Can you please confirm if it is available for 9.1.1?

Answer (score 1):

Publishing Service is not official a role in Azure Paas.

Ehab ElGindy who is part of the publishing Service Team describe on below link how you can have Publishing Service as an azure cloud service. 
http://www.ehabelgindy.com/run-sitecore-publishing-as-azure-cloud-service/

Corey Smith describe on below link how you can deploy your own Publishing Service using Arm Templates.

https://www.coreysmith.co/sitecore-publishing-service-deploy-to-azure-with-arm-templates/

These two ways are not official and Sitecore will not offer you support.

Answer (score 1):

In the described scenario I would most likely recommend using both the Sitecore Publishing Service as well as database replication to synchronize the two web datbases.

The Sitecore Publishing Service is an extremely fast option compared to the traditional publishing in Sitecore and it is not that hard to set up and run on Azure IaaS or PaaS if you feel adventurous.

However, instead of having to publish to two different web targets every time I would recommend looking into Azure geo-replication which is at least experimentally supported by Sitecore.

See https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/423602 for further details on database scaling support in Sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this great post from Corey Smith, it explains how to create the packages and modules to setup the publishing service in Azure PaaS.

https://www.coreysmith.co/sitecore-publishing-service-deploy-to-azure-with-arm-templates/